# Message error in Excel _how can I solve it?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone tell me how can I solve the following error? I get this error every time I enter a value in my cells. This Excel has a VBA script and based on the entered values, it runs a stored procedure.

The Excel runs correct, is just that I get this message all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code tries to add or remove a row in the upper table (unfortunately you failed to show the code).

Your tables don't have the same number of columns so when adding (or removing) the row would move only a part of the lower table(s) down which would corrupt the layout.

Possible Workarounds:

- Instead of inserting a table row, insert a row to the whole sheet.
- Organize your data so that tables are not stacked (show the tables next to each other, not above each other)
- Make sure all tables have the same number of columns.